# How can make volley if receive empty data from database show a (Toast.makeText ) android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an application that contains Google Maps I get data of google map from MySQL database by use Volley liberty to make connection between my application and database the code is work fine if database have Longitude and latitude but the problem if I not have data into Field of Longitude and latitude the app is crash.

How I can make  volley if receive empty data from database show a (Toast.makeText )or anything other but not crash my app?

```
 private void getMarkers() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("Response: ", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        String getObject = jObj.getString("location");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(getObject);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);
                            latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LG)));
                              addMarker(latLng, title);
                            gMap.animateCamera(zoomingLocation(latLng));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
    private CameraUpdate zoomingLocation(LatLng latLng) {
       return CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 7);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities of error in your case: data does not exist (`getString` returns null and `parseDouble` throws `NullPointerException`) or not formatted correctly (`parseDouble` throws `NumberFormatException`) neither of which you are handling.  So modify your loop to look like this and add any handling desired such as a toast in the exception block:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //title = jsonObject.getString(TITLE);

    // LT or LG strings may not exist (returns null) or not a valid double
    // so catch Exception (NullPointerException or NumberFormatException)
    try {
        latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LT)), Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(LG)));
        addMarker(latLng, title);
        gMap.animateCamera(zoomingLocation(latLng));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something about error such as display Toast.
    }
}
```

Note that if you display a toast it would be displayed on every error - so it may be better to simply set a flag in the exception block and then after the loop if the flag is true then display the toast ("Some data invalid").

Comment: Hi brother. Thank you, the code works well \ I apologize for the late reply. I had a different problem in the same code. Now everything is fine. Thank you